# rg.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [id] [DELETE FROM User WHERE user_id =:id ]

Tags: spring, hibernate

i am making a Q and A site using spring and hibernate and i am facing the error in deleting a user....
the error states...
rg.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [id] [DELETE FROM User WHERE user_id =:id ]

this error has been solved and now for reference my code is....

controller..........

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView deleteUser(@RequestParam("id") int user_id ) {
        userservice.deleteUser(user_id);
    return new ModelAndView("jsp/AdminUsers");

}
```

D A O ........

```
public void deleteUser(int user_id) {  
    User user = (User) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(User.class, user_id);
    if(null!=user){
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(user);
    }
}
```

Service....

```
 public void deleteUser(int user_id) {  
        userDao.deleteUser(user_id);  
    }
```

View Page URL...

```
/delete.html?id=${user.user_id}"
```

Comment: Why are you running both `createQuery/executeUpdate` and `delete`?

Comment: then what should be done sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that the error your getting is because you're running `createQuery("DELETE FROM User WHERE user_id =:id ")` and `executeUpdate` without binding the `:id` parameter. After creating the [`Query`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html), set the `id` parameter and then do `executeUpdate`. Also, there's no need to do both the query and the following `delete`.

Try this:

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("DELETE FROM User WHERE user_id =:id ");
query.setInteger("id", userId);
query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: You're still not setting the id on the query. Check my updated answer.

Comment: The method setInteger(String, int) is undefined for the type Query.

This error is displayed on making the change

Comment: error solved using ..

    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView deleteUser(@RequestParam("id") int user_id ) {
  userservice.deleteUser(user_id);
  return new ModelAndView("jsp/AdminUsers");
  
 }


this as the controller

Comment: I suggest you update your question with the code that works. It's pretty unreadable as it is.